# Ember Array Controller - function not loading

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember and I am trying to load a small array to the controller. The trouble is, the addCard function I've defined in cardsController is not showing up and I am getting the error: "object function() has no method 'addCard'". What am I doing wrong? I am using the following:

handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js,
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js,
ember-data.js

Here is my code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function(){
        //Populate content[] in cardController
        App.GetCards();
    }
});

App.GetCards = function(){
    card1 = App.Card.create({
                id: 0,
                title: 'Alabama',
                desc: 'Montgomery'
            });

    App.cardsController.addCard(card1);
};

App.Card = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    title: null,
    desc: null,
    current: true
});

App.cardsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],

    //Property that adds an item to content
    addCard: function(item){
        this.addObject(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that is is the only code that make up your app, you need to define the controller object direct after the Application create statement, and so `before` you use it, in this order:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function(){
    //Populate content[] in cardController
    App.GetCards();
  }
});

App.Card = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  title: null,
  desc: null,
  current: true
});

App.cardsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],

  //Property that adds an item to content
  addCard: function(item){
    this.addObject(item);
  }
});

App.GetCards = function(){
  card1 = App.Card.create({
            id: 0,
            title: 'Alabama',
            desc: 'Montgomery'
        });

  App.cardsController.addCard(card1);
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/40/) just for proof.

Comment: I just found my error. When creating the cardsController, I tried to extend the cardsController instead of actually creating it

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, fixed it in the answer for future folks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was working through an older Ember.js tutorial that had this code:

```
App.recentUsersController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addUser: function(name) {
        if( this.contains(name) ) this.removeObject(name);
        this.pushObject(name);
    },
    removeUser: function(view) {
        this.removeObject(view.context);
    },
    searchAgain: function(view) {
        App.tweetsController.set('username', view.context);
        App.tweetsController.loadTweets();
    },
    reverse: function(){
        return this.toArray().reverse();
    }.property('@each')
});
```

I kept getting the error `Error: Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties. Define computed properties using extend() or reopen() before calling create().`

Well, I took the very descriptive (and helpful) error message and combined that with what I know about chaining and I got this:

```
App.recentUsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    addUser: function(name) {
        if( this.contains(name) ) this.removeObject(name);
        this.pushObject(name);
    },
    removeUser: function(view) {
        this.removeObject(view.context);
    },
    searchAgain: function(view) {
        App.tweetsController.set('username', view.context);
        App.tweetsController.loadTweets();
    },
    reverse: function(){
        return this.toArray().reverse();
    }.property('@each')
}).create({});
```

First extend, then create. Worked for me and wanted to throw it out there in case anyone else ran into this issue working with older versions of Ember.